# iPhone Project crash on start

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to run my application and suddenly i get this error:

```
2014-11-05 12:12:54.972 [238:9512] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x235a7c1f 0x30dafc8b 0x235a7b65 0x299b61 0x299adf 0x322ec7 0x13b50d 0x242b6d6f 0x2356e377 0x2356d787 0x2356bded 0x234ba211 0x234ba023 0x2a86d0a9 0x26ac61d1 0x102bff 0x102b88)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It's on the start of the application,

i get this error without changing any code in my project, any idea what can cause this?

Comment: add your full crash report it is easy to optimize the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the `NSException` crashes, you have to remove all the warnings of `.xib`/.`storyboard` files. Cross check the `IBOutlets` warnings and you can see a cross (X) icon related to the yellow warnings to remove it.

[image]

[image]